# Carousel view gets overlap one page after getting in to it second time from master detail menu in iOS only it's working fine in Android in XAMARIN

Tags: ios, xamarin, view, carousel, master-detail

I'm making a demo application. In that I'm using carousel view in one page. carousel page has two access points. From one point it works fine. but when I'm accessing it from the master detail menu first time it works well because it gets information 1st time but when I open it second time from master detail menu, one page from the carousel view always shows on top.

What should I do to fix it?

Code Image is as below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akjnU.png)

Comment: have you use 
 ios:Page.PreferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation="Slide"
    ios:Page.UseSafeArea="True"

Comment: Can you please elaborate little more with code. It would be great for me because I'm new learner.

Comment: Please check this link

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/making-ios-11-even-easier-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Can you please share us your demo project? Also, don't post your code in image.